# Find a first-order logic sentence distinguishing two graphs

Tags: logic

Graph $G$ is the backbone of a cube ($8$ vertices, $12$ edges). In contrast, graph $H $ is a copy of a graph $ G $,  without exactly one edge ($8$ vertices, $11$ edges).

*Write a sentence distinguishing the two graphs with minimal nesting quantifiers.*

For me, it is very simple:
$ \forall_v deg (v) = 3$.
This sentence for $ G $ is true, however for $ H $ is not true. Unfortunately, it is not correct answer. I ask you for explaining me where I am wrong and how to solve it. On the whole, I have a problem with this type of task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you found the right property, but you didn't express it in the right way in a logical setting. When dealing with [logic on graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_of_graphs), a graph property is expressed by a logical formula whose variables represent graph vertices. Two predicates are allowed: equality ($v_1 = v_2$) and adjacency $E(v_1,v_2)$ interpreted as "there is an edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$. That being said, your property that all vertices have degree at least $3$ can be stated as follows:
$$
  \forall v\ \exists v_1\ \exists v_2\ \exists v_3\ \text{Diff}(v, v_1, v_2, v_3) \wedge E(v,v_1) \wedge E(v,v_2) \wedge E(v,v_3)
$$ 
where $\text{Diff}(v, v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is a sentence stating that $v, v_1, v_2, v_3$ are all distinct (I let you guess how you can express that in first order).

**Wrong**. However, it is possible to do better in terms of quantifier alternations: just express the fact that there exist 8 distinct vertices. You will of course need 8 existential quantifiers, but only one quantifier alternation.

EDIT. One could instead completely describe the graph $G$ by saying there exist 8 vertices, all distinct and describe all the edges of the graph. Not very concise but existential quantifiers would suffice.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are perfectly right. Edited.

Comment: "just express the fact that there exist 8 distinct vertices." After all, this sentence is true for both $G$ and $H$

Comment: @HaskellFun I missread the exercise. One should simply describe completely the graph. I edit my answer.

Comment: I would like to minimialize number of all quantifiers ? Not only $\forall$. Can you give me some hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence does indeed distinguish the two graphs. However, it is not of *minimal quantifier complexity*. Saying "all vertices have degree $3$" is a $\forall \exists^3\forall$-sentence (I don't know if the problem wants you to count every quantifier, or just alternations): "for every vertex, there exist three distinct vertices such that all vertices connected to the original are equal to one of the three".

EDIT: You asked for an explanation of (nesting) quantifier complexity. There are two different notions here; they each apply to sentences in *prenex normal form* (that is, a string of quantifiers followed by a quantifier-free formula), and basically count how many quantifiers there are. One notion of complexity counts quantifiers directly: so e.g. "$\forall x\exists y\exists z\forall a\forall b P(x, y, z, a, b)$" would have complexity $\forall\exists^2\forall^2$, or if we're going to give it a number, "$5$". The other notion of complexity counts *alternations* of quantifiers - similar quantifiers are "smooshed" together. So the previous sentence would be of complexity $\forall\exists\forall$, or "$3$". (Actually, in this context we like to keep track of the leading quantifier - so we'd say "$\Pi_3$" or "$\forall_3$".)

This second method may seem more ad hoc, but it's actually extremely useful especially in computability theory and set theory; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy). I don't know which version your class wants you to use; presumably somewhere they specifically define what kind of quantifier counting they're doing.

The point is: **you want to come up with a sentence distinguishing $G$ and $H$ which uses as few quantifiers as possible**.

So how are we going to improve that? Well, intuitively, deleting an edge makes a graph "less connected." So a good place to look is:

> What is the smallest size of a set of vertices such that *every* vertex outside that set is connected to one in the set?

Good news: saying that this number is $\le n$ is an $\exists^n\forall$-statement!

Bad news: this is a non-starter: both $G$ and $H$ have $n=2$.

Good news: we can tweak this example to get one that works. HINT: abgr gung gurer ner sbhe iregvprf bs $T$ fhpu gung nal bgure iregrk vf pbaarpgrq gb *guerr* bs gurz . . .

EDIT: Actually J.-E. Pin's answer is better in terms of quantifier complexity. But I'll leave this up in case it's helpful.

Comment: I ask for two things: 1. Try to explain me what does it mean exactly  degree of nesting  2. Can you hide solution in your answer ? Then in case of fail my trials I have a chance to learn more. Thanks in advance

Comment: @HaskellFun See my edits.

Comment: Can you be more precisely when it comes to tuning your hint ?